Should questions that include the word 'should' be closed
Should questions that include the word 'should', implying the existence of a commonly understood goal be closed?
I.e. "should the government help poor people?"
An example where 'should' does not imply a goal function: "Should I learn R if I want to be a business analyst?"

I don’t think it’s necessary to have any boolean logical rule as implied in the title.
If the question is about seeking opinions on what government should do or moral philosophy it should be closed.
However, for example someone could ask, suppose that social planner wants to minimize output gap, what should the social planner do, would be ok even though it still implies some moral goal.
The difference is that first question asks whether something is moral - not a domain of economics, the second has some objective (and every objective can be interpreted as a result of some sort of moral value judgement), but the question does not want to discuss the morality of the objective but actually the economics of achieving the objective in efficient manner which is what by definition economics studies.
Hence, I don’t think it’s possible to make the decision just based on the inclusion of word should together with some other binary rules (eg is the question about some government goal?). If this would be possible the site would not need any user moderation and just rely on bots and mods, but I don’t think that something like this is possible.
In any case, you can always vote close even if you are not 100% sure if the question should be closed, it takes 3 close votes to close question. If you personally think the question sounds too opinion seeking or breaks other possible rules you can always vote close even if you are not 100% sure it does.

"even though it still implies some moral goal"? How does trying to minimize the output gap imply a moral goal?

@Giskard It implies that minimizing output cap is desirable action by government

It does not; you made that goal an explicit assumption: "suppose that social planner wants to minimize output gap, what should the social planner do"; so the word 'should' has no moral (or any other) implications here.

@Giskard 1. I agree it’s not moral question because the question is not about desirability of the objective, I was using it as an example of question that is not moral question. 2. However, any (hypothetical) societal/individual goal is implicitly result of some value judgement. Even a utility function basically reflects a hypothetical representative agent’s moral judgements, eg having more of composite good x is good thing etc

1."I was using it as an example of question that is not moral question." You literally wrote it implies a moral goal! "suppose that social planner wants to minimize output gap, what should the social planner do, would be ok even though it still implies some moral goal."


"Even a utility function basically reflects a hypothetical representative agent’s moral judgements, eg having more of composite good x is good thing etc" So, this is besides the point for me as I will explain in the next comment but I have no clue how having a symmetrical Cobb-Douglas utility over some goods is a moral judgement in any way. Are you sure you are using the word correctly?


I think your answer misunderstands the question. If someone asks "assuming a symmetric C-D utility function and such and such constraints, what should a consumer consume to maximize their utility" then an objective answer is possible, since the goal function is provided as an assumption. But if someone asks "Given such and such constraints what should a consumer consume to maximize their utility" without specifying a utility function, then only an opinion based answer is possible. Such questions show that the one asking misunderstands the type of answers economics can provide.

@Giskard 1. if you would read the whole sentence I said this; “ the second has some objective (and every objective can be interpreted as a result of some sort of moral value judgement), but the question does not want to discuss the morality of the objective but actually the economics of achieving the objective in efficient manner which is what by definition economics studies.”


Yes it does. Moral judgements are any judgements about what is right or wrong. A utility function that that represents agents preferences also says what the agent think is the right or wrong amount of consumption given the agent situation. In fact any human individual or collective objective is a result of some moral judgement. However, if you read my bold part in 1, as I was saying just because there is some goal that implies moral judgements were made it doesn’t make the question moral philosophy question because the question is not about morality of the question but about optimization



"Moral judgements are any judgements about what is right or wrong. A utility function that that represents agents preferences also says what the agent think is the right or wrong amount of consumption" We often have discussions were I feel you are not admitting that you were wrong because of pure stubbornness and post incredible word salads instead. This is one of them!



I'm sorry, when you were writing about "first" and "second" questions you were writing about your example and not my questions? How...? What is your "first question" and what is your "second question" that you were referring to in this sentence, that you now claim is about your example?


I do hope you write a paper titled "The moral philosophy of eating strawberries instead of raspberries", seems like the kind of argument you would enjoy making!

@Giskard 1. Where am I wrong? You are asserting that as if it would be obvious without any explanation? I have a feeling that any time I present something that is widely accepted in mainstream economics or discussed in 101 economic classes you react to it like it’s something obviously wrong. I simply don’t even understand your objection to the statement that any human or societal objective implies that the human or group of humans made some moral judgements. This is public economics 101 you can see discussion of this even in philosophy of economics


You are making fun of it but there is actually a big literature about morality of eating certain food. In fact people were having moral discussions (due to religions) about eating certain kinds of meat or selfish literally since recorded history. For example, Muslims considering moral to eat chicken, although only if killed in certain way but not pork is literally like strawberry vs raspberry… but I guess you will now just assert I am wrong, and just can’t admit I am wrong, without any evidence or argument, and refuse to acknowledge this well known fact following with some  “fun” quip


Morality absolutely can shape preferences; I am a vegetarian of the animal rights variety. I just think its really nuts to assert that all preference come from morality. If I am the last person on Earth I will still have preferences, but they will not be due to morality. Anyway, I think words have lost their meaning (again), I cannot point out your contradictions any better. My fault, I am inadequate to the task. Have a nice afternoon/day/life!

@Giskard why would that be nuts? 1. If you open any moral philosophy/ethics textbook you would discover that what is moral is among other things literally based on personal values and ordering of values. Values, determine and shape preferences. In fact in philosophy common assertion is that humans are moral beings because of capability to reason. This is completely mainstream notion.


Morality generally speaking doesn’t require other people to exist. You said you are vegetarian due animal rights, presumably you would consider eating animal immoral even in absence of other people unless you are doing that just to conform with expectations of your peer group

